# How to read data from uploaded csv file and view it using django?

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views

How can I read uploaded csv file like in raw python? Path to file is ok.

views.py

```
def csv_read(request):
        
    with open('C:/Users/filepath.csv') as csv_file:
        rows = []
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            rows.append(row)

    
    context = {
        'rows': rows,
    }  

    
    return render(request, "dataframe.html", context)
```

dataframe.html

```
{% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if i get the question right. Do you want to display the file contents when opening a url?
And I understand raw as in no formatting, no table wrapping etc.

I think you can just directly return the file contents without inserting it in a template.
I did something similar really long ago. Try

```
with open('C:/Users/filepath.csv') as csv_file:
        data = csv_file.read()
        
response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='text/plain')
return response
```

This should then display the raw file contents when opening the url.